# Como extrair o Token do Header para armazenar no Local Storage?

Tags: python, angular, http, angular-6, jwt

Boa noite, galera!
Estou em uma batalha para conseguir recuperar o token que envio do meu backend para meu browser.

Segue código do meu Back em Python:

```
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('password', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        password = hashlib.md5(args['password'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = (%s) and password = (%s)"
        value = (args['username'], password)
        dbcursor.execute(sql, value)
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        if len(result) > 0:
            id_user = result[0][0]
            username = result [0][1]
            print(id_user)
            payload = {"id": id_user, "username": username}
            print(payload)
            authtoken = jwt.encode(payload, config.JWT.secret, algorithm='HS256')
            print(authtoken)
            data = json.dumps({"id": id_user, "username": result[0][1], "token": authtoken .decode("UTF-8)")})
            print(data)
            response = Response(str(data),mimetype='application/json')
            print(response)
            response.headers['x-access-token'] = "JWT" + authtoken.decode("UTF-8")
            print(response.headers)
            return response
        else:
            return {"message": "user invalido"}
```

Meu componente em Angular:

```
  userLogin(){
    const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService
        .authenticate(username, password)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      if (res ["message"] == 'user valido') {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
      }
      else {
        console.log('Caiu no else')
        this.loginForm.reset()
        this.platformDetectorService.isPlatformBrower() && this.usernameInput.nativeElement.focus()        
      }
    }
  )}
```

Meu service no Angular:

```
  authenticate(username: string, password: string) {    
    return this.http
      .post(
        API_URL,
        { "username":username, "password":password },
        { observe: 'response' } ) 
      .pipe(tap(res => {
        const authToken = res.headers.get('x-access-token')
        console.log(authToken)
      }))
  }
```

Segue foto do meu retorno no browser:

Está vindo 2 informaçõoes como mostro nas imagens abaixo:

Pela foto da pra ver q eu recebo 2 retornos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o meu primeiro retorno do tipo OPTIONS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o meu segundo retorno do tipo POST:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento acessar o x-access-token pelo meu componente do angular e printar no console ele me retorna 'null' como é mostrado na primeira imagem
No momento só estou printando para depois setar ele para o local storage